# Invalid addition of constness? Error: Cannot use char** to initialize const char**

Tags: c++, solaris, solaris-studio

Solaris Studio is generating the most puzzling of error messages.

```
158 char* inbufptr = buffer;
159 char* outbufptr = outbuf;
160 
161 const char** inbufptrpos = &inbufptr;
```

And the error message is:

> line 161: Error: Cannot use char** to initialize const char**.

Why should it be a problem to **add** constness? I am stuck, please help me out...

---

```
 memory: [m y _ c h a r _ a r r a y | inbufptr | inbufptr_pos]
          ^                           ^
          | (1)                       | (2)
          inbufptr                    inbufptrpos
```

The pointer char* inbufptr points to the beginning of the array, and does not promise to keep anything constant.

Now if I now have a pointer char const **inbufptr_pos this type promises not the change the contents of the array, but I can still change where the pointer points to. If I do that I have not changed the array and I don't see a problem with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an age-old problem, whereby intuitively you think you can "add `const`ness", but in fact adding `const`ness *indirectly* **violates** `const`-correctness.

The standard itself even has an example of it to help set people back on the correct path:

```
#include <cassert>  

int main() {  
  char* p = 0;  

  //char const** a = &p; // not allowed, but let's pretend it is  
  char const** a = (char const**)&p; // instead force the cast to compile  

  char const* orig = "original";  
  *a = orig; // type of *a is char const*, which is the type of orig, this is allowed  

  assert(p == orig); // oops! char* points to a char const*  
}
```

- http://kera.name/articles/2009/12/a-question-on-indirect-constness/

Comment: My answer wasn't that bad in comparison to this, or was it? I don't care about the reputation, I just want to see my mistake. Can you take a look please? :)

Comment: @G.Samaras: You didn't quite get the example right.

Comment: Can you please explain why so I can learn from my mistake? :)

Comment: @G.Samaras: Study this one and you'll see!

Comment: Thanks! Now it's clearer and I see why it's better than mine, +1! :)

Comment: @G.Samaras: Hint: `inpufptrpos` is not the problem (e.g. you can have `int x = 5; const int* ptr = &x; x = 6;` and not have trouble -- this is the equivalent of your example)

Answer (score -1):

Assume this was legal.

```
char* inbufptr = buffer;

const char** inpufptrpos = &inbufptr;
```

Now you can change `inbufptr`, but `inpufptrpos` is `const`, thus it should not be changed. You see that this doesn't make much sense. It's like `const` is not respected!

With the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468148/initialization-between-types-const-int-const-and-int-is-not-allowed-why) answer, I hope this helped! :)